# Como fazer queries síncronas com Sequelize no Node.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize-js

Comecei a estuar `Node.js` há pouco tempo e estou utilizando a divisão da lógica em módulos. Tenho um `UserSessionController` que valida se a sessão do usuário ainda é valida:

```
module.exports.getUserSession = function ( userToken ) {
    models.UserSession.find( {where : Sequelize.and(
        { token: userToken }, { dataExpira { lte: Date() } }) } ).complete ( function (err, user) {
            if (!!err) {
                console.log('Ocorreu um erro ao buscar a sessão do usuário:', err);
                return null;
            } else {
                return user;
            };
    })
}
```

mas quando tento executar esta chamada de um outro módulo, ao realizar a chamada o código segue sem receber o return, pois ele só será processado quando a query for completada.

```
usuarioLogado = userSession.getUserSession(token)
if (!!usuarioLogado) { //aqui usuarioLogado está undefined
  //faz a ação
} else {
  res.send(401, "Você deve estar logado para realizar alterações.");
  next();
}
```

como esta chamada é executada em um webservice `REST` a resposta para o cliente do WS ocorre antes da query ser executada no banco.

Existe uma forma de fazer com que uma chamada `Javascript` seja executada de forma **síncrona**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "beleza" do Node está em sua assincronicidade. Passe duas funções callback para `getUserSession`, assim:

```js
userSession.getUserSession(token, 
    function(err){
        res.send(401, "Você deve estar logado para realizar alterações.");
        next();
    }, 
    function(user){
        // faz alguma coisa com o usuario retornado
    });
```

E na função:

```js
module.exports.getUserSession = function (userToken, failure, success) {
    models.UserSession
               .find({where : Sequelize.and({token: userToken}, 
                                            {dataExpira : {lte: Date()}})
                      })
               .complete(function (err, user) {
                   if (!!err) {
                      return failure(err);
                   } else {
                      return success(user);
                   };
               });
}
```

Como eu não consigo testar, verifique se realmente é necessário o `return` antes da chamada dos callbacks.
Talvez você também queira retornar o código `403 - Forbidden` caso o usuário não esteja autenticado.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Estou tentando aprender este paradigma da assincronicidade, pois sempre trabalhei com liguagens imperativas. Obrigado